# odbc driver does not support the requested properties

Tags: mysql, vba, odbc

odbc driver does not support the requested properties error come when we run the program at last line can anyone please give me idea.

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsRec As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim query As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rsRec = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.connectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=127.0.0.1 ;Database=try;User=root;Password=root;"

conn.Open

query = "INSERT INTO user_table (Name)"
query = stSQL & "VALUES (Anupam)"

rsRec.Open query, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: This query does not return rows, use `connection.execute query` - there is no need for a recordset (which presumably fails due to the driver not supporting one of the lock/cursor options - neither of which are optimal for an insert anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:-

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsRec As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim query As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rsRec = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.connectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=127.0.0.1 ;Database=try;User=root;Password=root;"

conn.Open

query = "INSERT INTO user_table (Name) VALUES (Anupam)"

rsRec.Open query, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: @Anup Btw are you using this as a Macro in Excel??

Comment: yes i create a user form and make connection with mysql database.

Comment: But when i run this code that the show the error message that ODBC driver does not support the requested property and your code is also show same error please suggest some.

Answer (score 3):

I must note that this error is somewhat confusing since it also occurs when there is ANY typo in the SQL statement.
I for example had this error because a table was renamed and therefore did no longer exist.
When you encounter this error, check the spelling of all parameters and the table names.

Comment: precisely was my problem. the requested table did not exist.

Comment: I had the same error and the one column name in the query mismatched with the table. you saved my time, Thank you Steven