# SQL: Multiple OR in WHERE Clause (UP)

Tags: mysql, sybase

Can you give me a hand with this? I have variable string named "sql". Inside that variable, it holds a SQL Query. See below SQL. Actually, it has multiple OR in WHERE clause of SQL. And when i tried to open it in recordset there's an error. Note that, if the "OR condition in WHERE clause" are only 2 or let's say 3 it is running smoothly. My question is why I got this error? Is there something wrong in my SQL? I think none. But what is the main reason behind this error?

```sql
SELECT e.* FROM(
    SELECT d.* FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
                    pg.name, 
                    a.projectid, 
                    a.lrsid, 
                    a.start_chainage, 
                    a.end_chainage, 
                    p.name, 
                    p.categoryid, 
                    p.oa, 
                    p.originid, 
                    p.statusid, 
                    p.cost, 
                    p.userid, 
                    p.io, 
                    p.apc, 
                    '' as placeholder1, 
                    '' as placeholder2, 
                    '' as placeholder3, 
                    '' as placeholder4, 
                    pg.name, 
                    pip.programid, 
                    a.sectionlrscode, 
                    a.length, 
                    a.projectid + ',' + a.lrsid + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(decimal(9,2), a.start_chainage)) + ','  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(decimal(9,2), a.end_chainage)) + ',' + pg.name as multi  
        FROM        activity AS a 

        LEFT JOIN   project AS p 
            ON      p.projectid = a.projectid 

        LEFT JOIN   projectinprogram AS pip 
            ON      pip.projectid = a.projectid  

        LEFT JOIN   program AS pg 
            ON      pg.programid = pip.programid
    ) d 
    WHERE       d.multi = 'PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,418.00,625.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,625.00,785.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,785.00,982.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,4342.00,4569.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000701LZ,S03799LZ,4569.00,5211.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,24775.00,25017.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,25017.00,25224.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,28007.00,28289.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0006142LZ,S03799LZ,28278.00,28340.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001025LZ,S03564LZ,0.00,822.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005668LZ,S03564LZ,0.00,1722.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001062LZ,S03732LZ,23067.00,23267.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003370LZ,S03732LZ,23067.00,24085.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001062LZ,S03732LZ,24564.00,25314.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005201LZ,S03732LZ,25267.00,25314.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001062LZ,S03732LZ,30304.00,30974.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003378LZ,S03732LZ,30574.00,31754.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001066LZ,S03767LZ,8166.00,8663.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000704LZ,S03767LZ,7866.00,8166.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001271MN,S00639MN,49563.00,50109.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005313MN,S00639MN,49887.00,50280.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001275MN,S00610MN,8622.00,8767.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0006514MN,S00610MN,8752.00,8802.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001283MN,S00654MN,24318.00,24570.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001283MN,S00654MN,24570.00,24573.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001283MN,S00654MN,29769.00,30556.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001714MN,S00654MN,30556.00,31278.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001290MN,S00654MN,31527.00,32528.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001290MN,S00654MN,32528.00,32628.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001715MN,S00654MN,31278.00,31527.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001292MN,S00654MN,33037.00,33828.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001293MN,S00654MN,32981.00,33307.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001293MN,S00654MN,33307.00,33548.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001293MN,S00654MN,33548.00,33828.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001293MN,S00654MN,34123.00,34411.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000157MN,S00654MN,34411.00,34594.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001293MN,S00654MN,34594.00,35265.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001298MN,S00654MN,55714.00,56412.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001298MN,S00654MN,56412.00,56897.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001300MN,S00663MN,17713.00,18729.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000501MN,S00663MN,18729.00,19579.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001301MN,S00621MN,3630.00,4013.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005324MN,S00621MN,1526.00,3659.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005324MN,S00621MN,3659.00,3959.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005324MN,S00621MN,3959.00,4065.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001301MN,S00621MN,6952.00,7195.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005331MN,S00621MN,5558.00,7186.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005331MN,S00621MN,7186.00,7329.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001301MN,S00621MN,14780.00,15015.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001301MN,S00621MN,15015.00,15494.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001301MN,S00621MN,27337.00,27592.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005360MN,S00621MN,27555.00,27945.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001316MN,S01353MN,14963.00,15782.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000553MN,S01353MN,14400.00,14963.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000553MN,S01353MN,14963.00,15782.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001318MN,S01373MN,6084.00,6980.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001318MN,S01373MN,6980.00,7075.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001318MN,S01373MN,7434.00,7497.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001318MN,S01373MN,7497.00,8022.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001318MN,S01373MN,8022.00,9026.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001331MN,S00926MN,22225.00,23223.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000172MN,S00926MN,21529.00,22225.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001334MN,S01378MN,18188.00,18855.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001334MN,S01378MN,18855.00,19752.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000177MN,S01378MN,17459.00,18188.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,4145.00,4714.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003148MN,S00914MN,3235.00,4340.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,7121.00,7670.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003148MN,S00914MN,7453.00,8558.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,33464.00,34067.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,34067.00,34264.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,34610.00,34776.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,34776.00,35522.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000182MN,S00914MN,34610.00,34776.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,52714.00,53633.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000182MN,S00914MN,52714.00,53633.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,54158.00,54590.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,54590.00,54659.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,54659.00,55462.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000182MN,S00914MN,54659.00,55462.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000182MN,S00914MN,55462.00,56004.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001336MN,S00914MN,56592.00,57596.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000182MN,S00914MN,56592.00,57596.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001352MN,S00908MN,5780.00,6380.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0006552MN,S00908MN,6180.00,6260.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001353MN,S01011MN,3096.00,4430.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005337MN,S01011MN,4245.00,5302.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001364MN,S01006MN,235.00,506.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000190MN,S01006MN,506.00,1181.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001364MN,S01006MN,7195.00,7299.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001364MN,S01006MN,7299.00,7499.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001370MN,S00997MN,1207.00,1590.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003154MN,S00997MN,1207.00,1428.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001407MN,S00519MN,57879.00,58138.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001407MN,S00519MN,58138.00,58347.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001407MN,S00519MN,59382.00,59805.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000201MN,S00519MN,59382.00,60102.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001441MN,S00692MN,45.00,500.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001441MN,S00692MN,500.00,1417.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001445MN,S00392MN,2005.00,2659.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003176MN,S00392MN,1971.00,2247.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000508MN,S00392MN,1671.00,2005.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001447MN,S00446MN,6719.00,6756.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001447MN,S00446MN,6756.00,6881.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001451MN,S00439MN,15400.00,16333.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005242MN,S00439MN,16333.00,17895.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001451MN,S00439MN,71903.00,71927.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001451MN,S00439MN,71927.00,71948.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,17349.00,17741.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,17741.00,17879.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00017LZ,S00731LZ,16749.00,17349.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,64074.00,64120.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,64120.00,64398.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,64398.00,64588.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,64588.00,64670.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001519LZ,S01911LZ,639.00,1186.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00056LZ,S01911LZ,1186.00,2075.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000924LZ,S01911LZ,0.00,639.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001520LZ,S01917LZ,0.00,767.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00059LZ,S01917LZ,767.00,1397.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001523LZ,S04239LZ,4398.00,4464.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001523LZ,S04239LZ,4464.00,5411.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000691LZ,S04239LZ,3760.00,4464.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0006029LZ,S04239LZ,4469.00,4519.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000153MN,S00647MN,14753.00,14954.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000153MN,S00647MN,14954.00,15500.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000153MN,S00647MN,17213.00,17722.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000153MN,S00647MN,17722.00,18243.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001558LZ,S00319LZ,43678.00,46576.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001558LZ,S00319LZ,46421.00,46576.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000314LZ,S00319LZ,46421.00,46940.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000794LZ,S00319LZ,46008.00,46421.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001558LZ,S00319LZ,53338.00,53582.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005403LZ,S00319LZ,53582.00,56617.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001577LZ,S01030LZ,4952.00,6539.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0002934LZ,S01030LZ,4099.00,6539.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001584LZ,S00967LZ,18953.00,19596.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001584LZ,S00967LZ,19596.00,19956.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001600LZ,S01372LZ,1190.00,1427.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000634LZ,S01372LZ,679.00,1190.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001600LZ,S01372LZ,3654.00,4043.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000634LZ,S01372LZ,3240.00,3654.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001602LZ,S01373LZ,120.00,183.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000638LZ,S01373LZ,183.00,327.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001602LZ,S01373LZ,3441.00,3706.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000638LZ,S01373LZ,3241.00,3441.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000638LZ,S01373LZ,3706.00,3954.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001611MN,S00621MN,0.00,108.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005324MN,S00621MN,0.00,1226.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000161MN,S00621MN,7344.00,7461.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000161MN,S00621MN,7461.00,8318.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000161MN,S00621MN,30951.00,31458.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000161MN,S00621MN,31458.00,31962.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000161MN,S00621MN,31962.00,32369.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001621MN,S00458MN,126.00,536.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001621MN,S00458MN,536.00,678.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001621MN,S00458MN,678.00,976.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001621MN,S00458MN,1094.00,2005.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001621MN,S00458MN,2005.00,2934.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003177MN,S00458MN,76.00,2766.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01191LZ,1256.00,1395.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01191LZ,1395.00,1473.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01191LZ,1473.00,1623.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,1806.00,2395.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,2395.00,3301.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00049LZ,S01195LZ,3263.00,4204.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,3321.00,3400.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,3400.00,3460.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,6380.00,6932.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,6932.00,7015.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,7015.00,7394.50,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,7394.50,7533.50,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001701LZ,S00731LZ,3875.00,4025.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001701LZ,S00731LZ,4025.00,4210.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001709LZ,S03784LZ,38456.00,38715.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0001710LZ,S03784LZ,38715.00,39107.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000170LZ,S04074LZ,18368.00,20368.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0004993LZ,S04074LZ,20368.00,22224.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005254LZ,S04074LZ,17176.00,18588.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000172MN,S00926MN,18937.00,20221.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003142MN,S00926MN,18040.00,19857.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000172MN,S00926MN,24225.00,25230.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000172MN,S00926MN,25230.00,26216.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000172MN,S00926MN,26216.00,26565.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005809LZ,S00731LZ,16749.00,17249.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000188MN,S00957MN,39000.00,39807.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000188MN,S00957MN,39807.00,40346.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000194MN,S00476MN,0.00,389.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005351MN,S00476MN,0.00,436.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000194MN,S00485MN,13643.00,14176.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000194MN,S00485MN,14176.00,15132.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000194MN,S00485MN,26370.00,26856.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000194MN,S00485MN,26856.00,27448.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000194MN,S00485MN,43155.00,43873.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000194MN,S00485MN,43873.00,44454.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000201MN,S00519MN,49332.00,49845.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000201MN,S00519MN,49417.00,49845.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000208MN,S00126MN,3127.00,3236.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000208MN,S00126MN,3236.00,3608.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000208MN,S00126MN,4907.00,5076.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000208MN,S00126MN,5076.00,5256.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000208MN,S00126MN,5345.00,5861.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005062MN,S00126MN,0.00,5534.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00020LZ,S00760LZ,43365.00,43546.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00020LZ,S00760LZ,43546.00,43946.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000814LZ,S00760LZ,43946.00,44379.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000225MN,S00220MN,14036.00,14583.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000225MN,S00220MN,14583.00,14727.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000225MN,S00220MN,31804.00,32410.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000225MN,S00220MN,32410.00,32561.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000229MN,S00439MN,13928.00,14429.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005242MN,S00439MN,9400.00,14429.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000231MN,S00421MN,1068.00,2142.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000231MN,S00421MN,2142.00,5561.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000236LZ,S05991LZ,11761.00,12685.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005010LZ,S05991LZ,10269.00,12265.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000236LZ,S05991LZ,13249.00,14011.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000236LZ,S05991LZ,14011.00,14279.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000239LZ,S01313LZ,0.00,871.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000239LZ,S01313LZ,871.00,1290.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000239LZ,S01313LZ,12436.00,13293.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000239LZ,S01313LZ,13293.00,14123.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000248LZ,S05009LZ,8689.00,9585.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000248LZ,S05009LZ,9585.00,10503.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00024LZ,S00782LZ,6738.00,7487.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005150LZ,S00782LZ,4036.00,6953.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0006LZ,S00782LZ,7487.00,8020.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,53514.00,54093.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,54093.00,54749.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,54093.00,54851.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000832LZ,S00857LZ,53246.00,53514.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0005825LZ,S00857LZ,54696.00,54746.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,59750.00,59805.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,59805.00,59815.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,60451.00,60760.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000832LZ,S00857LZ,60760.00,61099.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000278LZ,S03955LZ,1823.00,2502.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000278LZ,S03955LZ,2502.00,3060.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003737LZ,S02043LZ,6502.00,11813.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003738LZ,S02043LZ,11813.00,15813.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003739LZ,S02057LZ,23667.00,25414.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003742LZ,S02057LZ,25414.00,27476.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003745LZ,S04252LZ,2562.00,6312.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003746LZ,S04252LZ,6312.00,7562.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003746LZ,S04252LZ,7562.00,8096.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003746LZ,S04252LZ,8096.00,10717.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003749LZ,S04252LZ,10717.00,12384.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003749LZ,S04252LZ,12384.00,13096.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003749LZ,S04252LZ,13096.00,16356.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003752LZ,S04253LZ,5033.00,7533.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003753LZ,S04253LZ,7533.00,9668.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003756LZ,S04227LZ,14497.00,14949.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003764LZ,S04227LZ,14949.00,15350.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000376LZ,S04312LZ,0.00,750.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000376LZ,S04312LZ,750.00,1610.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR000376LZ,S04312LZ,1610.00,2393.20,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003828MN,S01146MN,61016.00,64766.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003829MN,S01146MN,64766.00,66016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003829MN,S01146MN,66016.00,68516.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003831MN,S01146MN,68516.00,71016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003831MN,S01146MN,71016.00,72266.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003833MN,S01146MN,72266.00,76016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003834MN,S01146MN,76016.00,79766.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003835MN,S01146MN,79766.00,81016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003835MN,S01146MN,81016.00,83516.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003837MN,S01146MN,83516.00,86016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003838MN,S01146MN,86016.00,89766.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003839MN,S01146MN,89766.00,93292.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003841MN,S01038MN,30137.00,30812.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003849MN,S01038MN,30812.00,30901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003849MN,S01038MN,30901.00,31901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003849MN,S01038MN,31901.00,32338.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003849MN,S01038MN,32542.00,32722.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003849MN,S01038MN,32722.00,33442.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003849MN,S01038MN,33454.00,34901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003849MN,S01038MN,34901.00,35697.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003856MN,S01038MN,37816.00,37901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003856MN,S01038MN,37901.00,37994.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003856MN,S01038MN,37994.00,38146.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003856MN,S01038MN,38370.00,38870.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003856MN,S01038MN,38870.00,39184.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0006502MN,S01038MN,39181.00,39341.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003856MN,S01038MN,40901.00,41125.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003865MN,S01038MN,41125.00,41324.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003865MN,S01038MN,48419.00,48901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003865MN,S01038MN,48901.00,49008.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003865MN,S01038MN,49944.00,50140.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003876MN,S01038MN,50140.00,51146.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003883MN,S01038MN,53980.00,54218.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003883MN,S01038MN,54218.00,54901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003883MN,S01038MN,57150.00,57901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003883MN,S01038MN,57901.00,58901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003939MN,S01369MN,8871.00,9934.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        OR      d.multi='PR0003944MN,S01369MN,9934.00,10220.00,NEP 2016 Roads'
) e

WHERE       e.programid ='P_CO-ITTS-227_09172015_083200' 

ORDER BY    e.projectid, 
            e.start_chainage, 
            e.end_chainage ASC;
```

The error is:

> Error -2147217887 (ODBC driver does not support requested propertie.) in procedure OpenRecordset of Class Module clsViewERO

Comment: Add the compleate error message without blah blah blah

Comment: Right where you've decided to cut off the error message is probably some of the most important information. The error message is saying that something isn't supported - but you've decided not to *tell us* what feature the driver doesn't support.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - you can have multiple `WHERE` clauses if, as here, there are subqueries.

Comment: Hi Guys, 
Sorry for the inconvenience, this is the error
Error -2147217887 (ODBC driver does not support requested propertie.) in procedure OpenRecordset of Class Module clsViewERO

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever now it's readable, I can see that.

Comment: Are you connecting to SQL Server, or MySQL?

Comment: Its better to use **IN** instead of using lots of **OR**

Comment: There is no point nesting selects like that, you can add you where clause on the central select (use patenthesis), same thing for your order by clause.

Comment: To debug your request, just run the middle one with all the OR see if it works, if it doesn t it might have a syntax problem, so just add the OR clauses one by one till it break to isolate the problem.

Comment: If the syntax is ok, my guess is because your request is ridiculously long the odbc driver crash, apparently you can find a lot of similar error message on google that got fixed by upgrading the odbc driver.

Comment: Hi Damien, I am connecting to SYBASE, thanks.. VB6 + SYBASE to be specific.

Comment: @The thanks for such idea, ill try that later, but for now can we concentrate  for the error?

Comment: @LaurentFauvel, ok thanks, can you modify my SQL ? so that it will have a point.., A very big thanks for the isolation of the problem.. ill do that first before trying the "IN" ideas from "the". Thanks guys. =) I really appreciate this.

Comment: Similare case is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200154/odbc-driver-does-not-support-the-requested-properties). Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Laurent Fauvel,

Below is his answer..

It will be the exact same request at the difference your in clause will only have less lines. Like for example first request, you put the first 10 values of your initial in clause, second request the next 10 values, third the next 10... . But I think you can reduce the syntax a little bit in size (see comment about pg.name) and changing the configuration of your database might allow you to have just one request

Answer (score 0):

You are skipped the ")" during generate the column of 'multi'.
But as told earlier, better user IN instead of OR.
But it looks as you can put these constants into table variable and use them like table.

Comment: No, i didn't skip anything.. as i've said it is working on my SYBASE (i used it as a tool to run my script) it works.. but in VB6, when i tried to open it in RECORDSET, there's an error. Thanks for the time Vyacheslav. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            pg.name, 
            a.projectid, 
            a.lrsid, 
            a.start_chainage, 
            a.end_chainage, 
            p.name, 
            p.categoryid, 
            p.oa, 
            p.originid, 
            p.statusid, 
            p.cost, 
            p.userid, 
            p.io, 
            p.apc, 
            '' as placeholder1, 
            '' as placeholder2, 
            '' as placeholder3, 
            '' as placeholder4, 
            pg.name, 
            pip.programid, 
            a.sectionlrscode, 
            a.length, 
            a.projectid + ',' + a.lrsid + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(decimal(9,2), a.start_chainage)) + ','  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(decimal(9,2), a.end_chainage)) + ',' + pg.name as multi  
FROM activity AS a 
LEFT JOIN project AS p ON p.projectid = a.projectid
LEFT JOIN projectinprogram AS pip ON pip.projectid = a.projectid 
LEFT JOIN program AS pg ON pg.programid = pip.programid 
WHERE a.projectid + ',' + a.lrsid + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(decimal(9,2), a.start_chainage)) + ','  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(decimal(9,2), a.end_chainage)) + ',' + pg.name IN (
        'PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,418.00,625.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,625.00,785.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,785.00,982.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,4342.00,4569.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000701LZ,S03799LZ,4569.00,5211.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,24775.00,25017.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,25017.00,25224.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001010LZ,S03799LZ,28007.00,28289.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0006142LZ,S03799LZ,28278.00,28340.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001025LZ,S03564LZ,0.00,822.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005668LZ,S03564LZ,0.00,1722.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001062LZ,S03732LZ,23067.00,23267.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003370LZ,S03732LZ,23067.00,24085.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001062LZ,S03732LZ,24564.00,25314.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005201LZ,S03732LZ,25267.00,25314.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001062LZ,S03732LZ,30304.00,30974.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003378LZ,S03732LZ,30574.00,31754.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001066LZ,S03767LZ,8166.00,8663.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000704LZ,S03767LZ,7866.00,8166.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001271MN,S00639MN,49563.00,50109.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005313MN,S00639MN,49887.00,50280.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001275MN,S00610MN,8622.00,8767.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0006514MN,S00610MN,8752.00,8802.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001283MN,S00654MN,24318.00,24570.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001283MN,S00654MN,24570.00,24573.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001283MN,S00654MN,29769.00,30556.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001714MN,S00654MN,30556.00,31278.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001290MN,S00654MN,31527.00,32528.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001290MN,S00654MN,32528.00,32628.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001715MN,S00654MN,31278.00,31527.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001292MN,S00654MN,33037.00,33828.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001293MN,S00654MN,32981.00,33307.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001293MN,S00654MN,33307.00,33548.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001293MN,S00654MN,33548.00,33828.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001293MN,S00654MN,34123.00,34411.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000157MN,S00654MN,34411.00,34594.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001293MN,S00654MN,34594.00,35265.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001298MN,S00654MN,55714.00,56412.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001298MN,S00654MN,56412.00,56897.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001300MN,S00663MN,17713.00,18729.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000501MN,S00663MN,18729.00,19579.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001301MN,S00621MN,3630.00,4013.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005324MN,S00621MN,1526.00,3659.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005324MN,S00621MN,3659.00,3959.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005324MN,S00621MN,3959.00,4065.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001301MN,S00621MN,6952.00,7195.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005331MN,S00621MN,5558.00,7186.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005331MN,S00621MN,7186.00,7329.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001301MN,S00621MN,14780.00,15015.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001301MN,S00621MN,15015.00,15494.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001301MN,S00621MN,27337.00,27592.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005360MN,S00621MN,27555.00,27945.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001316MN,S01353MN,14963.00,15782.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000553MN,S01353MN,14400.00,14963.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000553MN,S01353MN,14963.00,15782.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001318MN,S01373MN,6084.00,6980.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001318MN,S01373MN,6980.00,7075.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001318MN,S01373MN,7434.00,7497.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001318MN,S01373MN,7497.00,8022.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001318MN,S01373MN,8022.00,9026.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001331MN,S00926MN,22225.00,23223.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000172MN,S00926MN,21529.00,22225.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001334MN,S01378MN,18188.00,18855.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001334MN,S01378MN,18855.00,19752.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000177MN,S01378MN,17459.00,18188.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,4145.00,4714.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003148MN,S00914MN,3235.00,4340.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,7121.00,7670.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003148MN,S00914MN,7453.00,8558.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,33464.00,34067.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,34067.00,34264.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,34610.00,34776.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,34776.00,35522.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000182MN,S00914MN,34610.00,34776.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,52714.00,53633.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000182MN,S00914MN,52714.00,53633.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,54158.00,54590.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,54590.00,54659.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,54659.00,55462.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000182MN,S00914MN,54659.00,55462.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000182MN,S00914MN,55462.00,56004.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001336MN,S00914MN,56592.00,57596.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000182MN,S00914MN,56592.00,57596.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001352MN,S00908MN,5780.00,6380.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0006552MN,S00908MN,6180.00,6260.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001353MN,S01011MN,3096.00,4430.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005337MN,S01011MN,4245.00,5302.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001364MN,S01006MN,235.00,506.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000190MN,S01006MN,506.00,1181.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001364MN,S01006MN,7195.00,7299.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001364MN,S01006MN,7299.00,7499.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001370MN,S00997MN,1207.00,1590.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003154MN,S00997MN,1207.00,1428.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001407MN,S00519MN,57879.00,58138.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001407MN,S00519MN,58138.00,58347.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001407MN,S00519MN,59382.00,59805.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000201MN,S00519MN,59382.00,60102.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001441MN,S00692MN,45.00,500.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001441MN,S00692MN,500.00,1417.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001445MN,S00392MN,2005.00,2659.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003176MN,S00392MN,1971.00,2247.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000508MN,S00392MN,1671.00,2005.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001447MN,S00446MN,6719.00,6756.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001447MN,S00446MN,6756.00,6881.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001451MN,S00439MN,15400.00,16333.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005242MN,S00439MN,16333.00,17895.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001451MN,S00439MN,71903.00,71927.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001451MN,S00439MN,71927.00,71948.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,17349.00,17741.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,17741.00,17879.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00017LZ,S00731LZ,16749.00,17349.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,64074.00,64120.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,64120.00,64398.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,64398.00,64588.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001498LZ,S00731LZ,64588.00,64670.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001519LZ,S01911LZ,639.00,1186.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00056LZ,S01911LZ,1186.00,2075.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000924LZ,S01911LZ,0.00,639.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001520LZ,S01917LZ,0.00,767.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00059LZ,S01917LZ,767.00,1397.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001523LZ,S04239LZ,4398.00,4464.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001523LZ,S04239LZ,4464.00,5411.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000691LZ,S04239LZ,3760.00,4464.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0006029LZ,S04239LZ,4469.00,4519.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000153MN,S00647MN,14753.00,14954.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000153MN,S00647MN,14954.00,15500.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000153MN,S00647MN,17213.00,17722.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000153MN,S00647MN,17722.00,18243.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001558LZ,S00319LZ,43678.00,46576.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001558LZ,S00319LZ,46421.00,46576.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000314LZ,S00319LZ,46421.00,46940.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000794LZ,S00319LZ,46008.00,46421.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001558LZ,S00319LZ,53338.00,53582.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005403LZ,S00319LZ,53582.00,56617.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001577LZ,S01030LZ,4952.00,6539.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0002934LZ,S01030LZ,4099.00,6539.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001584LZ,S00967LZ,18953.00,19596.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001584LZ,S00967LZ,19596.00,19956.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001600LZ,S01372LZ,1190.00,1427.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000634LZ,S01372LZ,679.00,1190.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001600LZ,S01372LZ,3654.00,4043.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000634LZ,S01372LZ,3240.00,3654.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001602LZ,S01373LZ,120.00,183.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000638LZ,S01373LZ,183.00,327.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001602LZ,S01373LZ,3441.00,3706.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000638LZ,S01373LZ,3241.00,3441.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000638LZ,S01373LZ,3706.00,3954.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001611MN,S00621MN,0.00,108.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005324MN,S00621MN,0.00,1226.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000161MN,S00621MN,7344.00,7461.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000161MN,S00621MN,7461.00,8318.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000161MN,S00621MN,30951.00,31458.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000161MN,S00621MN,31458.00,31962.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000161MN,S00621MN,31962.00,32369.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001621MN,S00458MN,126.00,536.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001621MN,S00458MN,536.00,678.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001621MN,S00458MN,678.00,976.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001621MN,S00458MN,1094.00,2005.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001621MN,S00458MN,2005.00,2934.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003177MN,S00458MN,76.00,2766.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01191LZ,1256.00,1395.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01191LZ,1395.00,1473.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01191LZ,1473.00,1623.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,1806.00,2395.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,2395.00,3301.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00049LZ,S01195LZ,3263.00,4204.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,3321.00,3400.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,3400.00,3460.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,6380.00,6932.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,6932.00,7015.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,7015.00,7394.50,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001679LZ,S01195LZ,7394.50,7533.50,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001701LZ,S00731LZ,3875.00,4025.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001701LZ,S00731LZ,4025.00,4210.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001709LZ,S03784LZ,38456.00,38715.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0001710LZ,S03784LZ,38715.00,39107.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000170LZ,S04074LZ,18368.00,20368.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0004993LZ,S04074LZ,20368.00,22224.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005254LZ,S04074LZ,17176.00,18588.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000172MN,S00926MN,18937.00,20221.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003142MN,S00926MN,18040.00,19857.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000172MN,S00926MN,24225.00,25230.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000172MN,S00926MN,25230.00,26216.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000172MN,S00926MN,26216.00,26565.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005809LZ,S00731LZ,16749.00,17249.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000188MN,S00957MN,39000.00,39807.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000188MN,S00957MN,39807.00,40346.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000194MN,S00476MN,0.00,389.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005351MN,S00476MN,0.00,436.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000194MN,S00485MN,13643.00,14176.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000194MN,S00485MN,14176.00,15132.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000194MN,S00485MN,26370.00,26856.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000194MN,S00485MN,26856.00,27448.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000194MN,S00485MN,43155.00,43873.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000194MN,S00485MN,43873.00,44454.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000201MN,S00519MN,49332.00,49845.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000201MN,S00519MN,49417.00,49845.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000208MN,S00126MN,3127.00,3236.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000208MN,S00126MN,3236.00,3608.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000208MN,S00126MN,4907.00,5076.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000208MN,S00126MN,5076.00,5256.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000208MN,S00126MN,5345.00,5861.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005062MN,S00126MN,0.00,5534.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00020LZ,S00760LZ,43365.00,43546.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00020LZ,S00760LZ,43546.00,43946.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000814LZ,S00760LZ,43946.00,44379.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000225MN,S00220MN,14036.00,14583.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000225MN,S00220MN,14583.00,14727.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000225MN,S00220MN,31804.00,32410.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000225MN,S00220MN,32410.00,32561.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000229MN,S00439MN,13928.00,14429.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005242MN,S00439MN,9400.00,14429.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000231MN,S00421MN,1068.00,2142.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000231MN,S00421MN,2142.00,5561.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000236LZ,S05991LZ,11761.00,12685.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005010LZ,S05991LZ,10269.00,12265.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000236LZ,S05991LZ,13249.00,14011.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000236LZ,S05991LZ,14011.00,14279.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000239LZ,S01313LZ,0.00,871.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000239LZ,S01313LZ,871.00,1290.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000239LZ,S01313LZ,12436.00,13293.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000239LZ,S01313LZ,13293.00,14123.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000248LZ,S05009LZ,8689.00,9585.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000248LZ,S05009LZ,9585.00,10503.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00024LZ,S00782LZ,6738.00,7487.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005150LZ,S00782LZ,4036.00,6953.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0006LZ,S00782LZ,7487.00,8020.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,53514.00,54093.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,54093.00,54749.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,54093.00,54851.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000832LZ,S00857LZ,53246.00,53514.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0005825LZ,S00857LZ,54696.00,54746.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,59750.00,59805.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,59805.00,59815.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR00025LZ,S00857LZ,60451.00,60760.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000832LZ,S00857LZ,60760.00,61099.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000278LZ,S03955LZ,1823.00,2502.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000278LZ,S03955LZ,2502.00,3060.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003737LZ,S02043LZ,6502.00,11813.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003738LZ,S02043LZ,11813.00,15813.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003739LZ,S02057LZ,23667.00,25414.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003742LZ,S02057LZ,25414.00,27476.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003745LZ,S04252LZ,2562.00,6312.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003746LZ,S04252LZ,6312.00,7562.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003746LZ,S04252LZ,7562.00,8096.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003746LZ,S04252LZ,8096.00,10717.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003749LZ,S04252LZ,10717.00,12384.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003749LZ,S04252LZ,12384.00,13096.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003749LZ,S04252LZ,13096.00,16356.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003752LZ,S04253LZ,5033.00,7533.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003753LZ,S04253LZ,7533.00,9668.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003756LZ,S04227LZ,14497.00,14949.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003764LZ,S04227LZ,14949.00,15350.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000376LZ,S04312LZ,0.00,750.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000376LZ,S04312LZ,750.00,1610.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR000376LZ,S04312LZ,1610.00,2393.20,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003828MN,S01146MN,61016.00,64766.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003829MN,S01146MN,64766.00,66016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003829MN,S01146MN,66016.00,68516.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003831MN,S01146MN,68516.00,71016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003831MN,S01146MN,71016.00,72266.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003833MN,S01146MN,72266.00,76016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003834MN,S01146MN,76016.00,79766.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003835MN,S01146MN,79766.00,81016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003835MN,S01146MN,81016.00,83516.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003837MN,S01146MN,83516.00,86016.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003838MN,S01146MN,86016.00,89766.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003839MN,S01146MN,89766.00,93292.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003841MN,S01038MN,30137.00,30812.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003849MN,S01038MN,30812.00,30901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003849MN,S01038MN,30901.00,31901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003849MN,S01038MN,31901.00,32338.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003849MN,S01038MN,32542.00,32722.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003849MN,S01038MN,32722.00,33442.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003849MN,S01038MN,33454.00,34901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003849MN,S01038MN,34901.00,35697.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003856MN,S01038MN,37816.00,37901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003856MN,S01038MN,37901.00,37994.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003856MN,S01038MN,37994.00,38146.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003856MN,S01038MN,38370.00,38870.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003856MN,S01038MN,38870.00,39184.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0006502MN,S01038MN,39181.00,39341.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003856MN,S01038MN,40901.00,41125.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003865MN,S01038MN,41125.00,41324.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003865MN,S01038MN,48419.00,48901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003865MN,S01038MN,48901.00,49008.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003865MN,S01038MN,49944.00,50140.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003876MN,S01038MN,50140.00,51146.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003883MN,S01038MN,53980.00,54218.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003883MN,S01038MN,54218.00,54901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003883MN,S01038MN,57150.00,57901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003883MN,S01038MN,57901.00,58901.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003939MN,S01369MN,8871.00,9934.00,NEP 2016 Roads' 
        ,'PR0003944MN,S01369MN,9934.00,10220.00,NEP 2016 Roads')
AND pip.programid ='P_CO-ITTS-227_09172015_083200' 
ORDER BY a.projectid, 
         a.start_chainage, 
         a.end_chainage ASC;
```

With an IN and no nested Select. But I didn't correct any syntax error if there is one.

Comment: You're great Laurel, thanks.. but i have one question is there difference between your code "NO NESTED SELECT" to my code which has "NESTED SELECT" ?

Comment: Yup, nested select requests are performances killers because they lose the use of indexes (your nested select become a sort of temporary table without index). Also they are painfull to maintain. In your case it is a minor issue but just a matter of having good habits when writing sql.

Comment: Also there is no difference in term of result btw mine and your normally.

Comment: Hi @laurent, I tried your idea, modified my SQL and turned it to NON NESTED SQL then used IN than OR... but the problem is still there.. I guess the answer is SQL LIMIT, I reached the limitation of SQL but I don't know how to cope with this. Any suggestions idol?

Comment: Yep, from what i read it might be an issue with your odbc driver needing an upgrade and not related to your sql syntax (even if some syntax cleaning was well worth it). Maybe post info on the driver used and wich language is launching the request... so someone can help you.

Comment: Thanks for helping Laurent but there's no problem with my ODBC.. The real problem is in the SQL, SQL has a limitation and i reached it because of this long long long code... i just want someone, can give me an idea to solve this issue.. please check this link especially the comments of our fellows stackoverflowers..  ."http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738118/sql-problems-multiple-or-in-where-clause/32751396#32751396"

Comment: Your request is just extracting content, so if the problem is really in the request being too long, you could cut it in 5 requests for exemple by just duplicating the request and leaving only 20 or so values in the IN for each of them. And after you concatenate the results and order them with code.

Comment: Also you could redux the IN syntax, because for exemple it seems you are allways looking for pg.name = 'NEP 2016 road' so no need to repeat it in all the IN values.

Comment: You should take a look in your sql server configuration, there are a lot of limits potentially blocking you here (not just the sql request lenght but also the number of or (in) clauses allowed... ).

Comment: I really really really thank you. haha, nice ideas Sir Laurent "Duplicating the request" nice.. can you give me a sample with this? just a small query will do. I  just wanna know how you duplicate requests in SQL. THANKS. =)

Comment: It will be the exact same request at the difference your in clause will only have less lines. Like for example first request, you put the first 10 values of your initial in clause, second request the next 10 values, third the next 10... . But I think you can reduce the syntax a little bit in size (see comment about pg.name) and changing the configuration of your database might allow you to have just one request.

Comment: Thanks, GOT IT! xD How can I commend you ? xD :salute: Sir Laurent ! xD

Comment: No problem, just vote up the solution that helped you the most so peoples with similar problems can find a way around and try to spend time helping others on subjects you know well. It will be the best way to thanks the community ;)